# Recover file corrupted due to power cut off

Tags: windows

A file I was working on was corrupted (filename.css) due to power cutoff. The file size is same but when I open it with dreamweaver it show blank.
If I open it with notepad++ it shows like this:

```
NUL NUL NUL NUL NUL NUL NUL
```

How can I recover this file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the obvious answer is that you recover the file from your latest backup, but I'm guessing that because your asking this question, you don't have one?

If that's the case, then your pretty limited in what you can do. If you have saving of previous versions turned on in Windows you may be able to load an older version by right clicking on the file, go to properties and look at previous versions.

However, more than likely you are going to have to accept that it is gone, learn your lesson and start doing regular backups.

Answer (score 8):

You can use RECUVA, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: RECUVA process screenshrt]

Make sure you "cancel" the wizard in the beginning and go straight away into the software.

Then:

1. Type   *.txt|   in the "Filename or Path" box
2. Click on options
3. In the "Actions" Tab, select "Scan for Non-deleted files".

Now search. Boom You can find your file.

Save it to another partition and ENJOY
Refer the picture below for more info.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The file is not deleted. It is corrupted. Hence Recuva can do noting.

Comment: @Fleet Command This answer actually worked in my case, power shortage left me with "nul nul nul ..." python file and recuva managed to recover it.

Comment: yes Recuva works wonders, it helped me restore an HTML file damaged by power outage after R-Studio failed miserably

Comment: I agree too. Recuva worked perfectly for me also for recovering a corrupt .cs(C# code) file.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, I had a critical piece of source code that I was working on when the power outage occured. When I opened the file in NP++ it showed a bunch of NULLS and I had not taken a backup for months!! I followed all the steps in this answer to the tee and voila!! I found my file 100% intact right till the last update i made.

Comment: 1000 upvotes. Worked like a magic.

Comment: Would be great if someone could explain WHY this works when the file shows NULs... Is the problem with a pointer, rather than the file itself?

Comment: This works. Notepad++ was saving file, and the BSOD happened right then. I scanned the entire drive though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Recuva software if no backup is done.

My file got corrupted due to power cut off ,so installed [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) (free software for undelete) and searched in that folder with Recuva. It was able to recover my file.

Hope this help.......

Comment: Note that by merely downloading or installing the software, you could be overwriting the parts that you are trying to recover.

Comment: Recuva cannot recover corrupted files; I can only recover deleted files.

Comment: @Fleet Command, it absolutely can, i'm the living proof, especially that is has a relevant option in the scan settings

Comment: I am another LIVING Proof. I have written a huge amount of code in 1 hour and suddenly Laptop shutdown and rebooted. I opened my file and there was NUL-NUL-NUL n times in that file. I googled for solution, found this answer. Then downloaded and installed Recuva and ran a deep scan in the folder and hurray I got my file.......

Answer (score 3):

Restore it from your backup. If you don't have a backup, you are out of luck.