# Problems recovering a corrupted file

Tags: windows, notepad++, data-recovery

Yesterday I was working on a textfile in Notepad++, at some point Notepad++ crashed and since then the file is completely empty and its size shows up as 0 Bytes.

I don't have any backups of this file, so I tried following this advice: https://superuser.com/a/1179489

Recuva seems to find a recoverable version of that file, which is about 24KB, which should be about the right size. However when I try to recover the file using Recuva, the restored version is 0 Bytes and completely empty again.

Is there any way to recover the file, or at least an explanation why Recuva shows the size as 24KB and then recovers a 0 Bytes file anyways?

Comment: While most recovery software is pretty much identical, this might be the case, where you need to use a different tool to verify the file fragment being found actually is 24 KB.

Comment: It might find a directory entry stating it’s 24k etc but the part on the disk that it points to may have been emptied/overwritten so the data isn’t there.

Comment: Have you tried [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)?  If you have show hidden files enabled in Explorer, have you checked the directory the file was in to see if a cache file was created that might still be there or within `%LocalAppData%\Temp`, `%LocalAppData%\Notepad++`, or `%AppData%\Notepad++`?  I would also recommend enabling auto-backup of files to a backup directory every 1min within Notepad++'s settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried a few different recovery tools now, most don't find the file at all and the others can only recover a 0 Bytes version. There's also no cache files in the original directory or in the AppData directories, so I suppose there really is just some directory entry that says its 24KB, but the actual data is completely gone. Luckily it wasn't a very important file, but that's still annoying.